# Python Flask Uploading Image to S3 - random filename from nowhere overwritten

Tags: python, flask

Well I am currently facing a weird issue where my filename (which is correctly generated is overwritten with something random).

I am using this code to upload to AWS3, here the code checks wether a file with such name exists already in the bucket and if it does, it adds a `1` to the end of the file, then it keeps checking for existing files and increments the number until the filename is unique.

I tested the code in a seperate python file and it seemed to work fine, but here my filename is overwritten with random stringname `b1.a`

I was debugging now for a while and I have no clue. I remember having something similar a while ago, where a missing favicon caused the issue (probably someone knows what was going on and how these issues are connected). But this time I cant figure out what happened.

```
k.key = bucketpath + filename_hauptbild
if k.key in bucket:
    new_filename_haupt_split = filename_hauptbild.split(".")
    while k.key in bucket:
        if new_filename_haupt_split[0][-1] not in "0123456789":
            new_filename_haupt = new_filename_haupt_split[0] + "1." + new_filename_haupt_split[1]
        else:
            new_filename_haupt = new_filename_haupt_split[0][:-1] + str(int(new_filename_haupt_split[0][-1]) + 1) + "." + new_filename_haupt_split[1]
        new_filename_haupt_split = new_filename_haupt
        k.key = bucketpath + new_filename_haupt
        print  "this", new_filename_haupt
    k.key = bucketpath + new_filename_haupt
    filename_hauptbild = new_filename_haupt
    k.set_contents_from_string(file_contents)
else:
    k.set_contents_from_string(file_contents)

print filename_hauptbild
setattr(model_to_change, model_column, filename_hauptbild)
```

Notice here:
I use `2 x prints` and the output shows 3 lines.
The first `print  "this", new_filename_haupt` shows initialy the correct filename but is overwritten by `b1.a`:

Console output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your filename, you don't properly update your `_split` variable:

```
new_filename_haupt_split = new_filename_haupt
```

hence, on the next loop when you call `new_filename_haupt_split[0]` you just get the first letter of the filename - `b`  - rather than the filename itself, and when you call `new_filename_haupt_split[1]` you get the second letter - `a` - rather than the extension. Hence the name `b1.a`. Change your line to:

```
new_filename_haupt_split = new_filename_haupt.split(".")
```

and I think this should work.

EDIT: you could re-write this as a function to make your life a little easier. Here's an example of the kind of approach you might require:

```
bucket = ['baubedarf.png', 'baubedarf1.png']

def get_filename(input_filename, all_files):
    if input_filename in all_files:
        filename, ext = input_filename.rsplit('.', 1)
        counter = 1
        while '{}{}.{}'.format(filename, counter, ext) in all_files:
            counter += 1
        return '{}{}.{}'.format(filename, counter, ext)
    else:
        return input_filename

print get_filename('baubedarf.png', bucket)
```

Comment: Figured it out already and fixed it, really stupid mistake. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Roman you might want to try re-writing it as a function if you can - I've edited in an example of how this might work